# Vuejs is not refresh other component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two components. Component 1:

```
<template>
<div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="group">Category</label>

    <select name="category" v-model="category" @change="setCategory(category)" class="form-control select-group" id="category">
        <option value="1">Category 1</option>
        <option value="2">Category 2</option>
    </select>
</div>

<tags-multiselect :categoryId="category"></tags-multiselect>

</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      category: 1,
    }
  },

  methods: {
    setCategory(selected) {
      this.category = selected;
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Component 2:

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card card-default">
                <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    I'm an example component.
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['categoryId'],
        data () {
         return {
           category_ids: this.categoryId
        }
        },
        created() {
        axios.post('/tags', { category_id: this.categoryId })
          .then((response) => {
              this.tags = response.data;
          })
          .catch((err) => {

          })
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I select option from first component, I not update `category_id` on second component with other id I get only `1` id. How I can resolve this? How I can refresh the second component with new selected data from select field?
Axios is not working. Why? Axios is not read props.

Comment: How are they related to each other? Are they sibling components? Parent and child?

Comment: https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of things that needed to be fixed in order for your code to work properly. Firstly, on the parent component you can remove the `v-model="category"` and change the `@change="setCategory(category)"` to `@change="setCategory"`

Your select will be: `<select name="category" @change="setCategory" class="form-control select-group" id="category">`

And in the method use the event target value attribute to get the selected value, this way Vue will detect the changes and update the props in the child:

```
  methods: {
    setCategory(e) {
      this.category = e.target.value;
    }
  },
```

So your component 1 would be:

```
<template>
<div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="group">Category</label>

    <select name="category" @change="setCategory" class="form-control select-group" id="category">
        <option value="1">Category 1</option>
        <option value="2">Category 2</option>
    </select>
</div>

<tags-multiselect :categoryId="category"></tags-multiselect>

</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            category: 1,
        }
    },
  methods: {
    setCategory(e) {
      this.category = e.target.value;
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

In the child component I created the variable axiosReponseData to store the response of the axios call (You can name it whatever you want). You should do the following to get it fixed:

- Move the axios call to a new method (lets call it performRequest())
- Call performRequest() on mounted()
- Add a watcher to the prop (categoryId), so whenever it changes this watcher will call the performRequest() method and update the data.

So the the code in your child component will be:

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card card-default">
                <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>
                <div class="card-body" v-if="axiosReponseData">

                    I'm an example component.
                    {{axiosReponseData.id}}
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
    export default {
        props: ['categoryId'],
        data () {
            return {
                axiosReponseData: null
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.performRequest();
        },
        methods:
        {
            performRequest() {
                if (this.categoryId){
                    axios.post('/tags', { category_id: this.categoryId })
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.axiosReponseData = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {

                    })
                }
                else {
                    this.axiosReponseData = null;
                } 
            }
        },
        watch: {
            categoryId: function () {
                this.performRequest();
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

Also you don't need the category_ids variable since it is the same as the props.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the problem is with the name **category_id** in second component, it should be **'category-id'** or **categoryId**.

Comment: no this is not working. When I select option, on second component categoryId is not update

Comment: Are you registering the components properly? try to show attribute from parent in child component. Maybe try switching from globally registered to locally registered component.

Answer (score -1):

The problem I think is with the name of your props. in Component 1 you are passing data to prop `category-id`

```
<tags-multiselect :category-id="category"></tags-multiselect>
```

whereas in Component 2 you are expecting prop named `categoryId`.

```
props: ['categoryId'],
```

just make these consistent and it will work for you.

here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WaleedAli070/xywej78n/9/)

And, BTW, you don't need to redeclare a prop with a different name in `data ()` just to make it reactive. the props already are reactive similar to data properties.

Comment: not working... :( On onchange select, data is not show

Comment: yes.. `Vue.component('select-category', require('./components/SelectCategoryComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('tags-multiselect', require('./components/TagsSelectComponent.vue').default);`

Comment: I have added a demo fiddle, see if that helps you out.

Comment: @waleedali on `mounted` method not working :) try do `console.log(categoryId)` inside `mounted`

Comment: first of all, it's `console.log(this.categoryId)` you are missing `this` in here. secondly, this mounted function/hook will only be called once (at the time of mounting the component) and there is a higher chance that, since the `categoryId` is being passed as a prop to the child component, it appears `undefined` at that time. 

if you want to console log in the child component every time the parent property changes, consider using `updated ()` hook instead of `mounted ()`